# failed to open stream - wp-includes/blocks/file.php

Tags: fatal-error, warnings

I am troubleshooting an association with their wordpress site which seems to have made an automatic update. Since then, if I activate the debug I have this (see photos). I went to see the file.php file but it is not there.

[image]

Comment: you mean https://github.com/WordPress/WordPress/blob/master/wp-includes/blocks/index.php? Looks like their WP install is incomplete, grab the latest WP and replace your `wp-includes` folder with a fresh good version. You probably want to do the same for the rest of WP

Comment: Nice, thanks, the update was not complete